# Is there a way to join 'distant' lines in vscode?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code, text

My data is in a format I'd like to change

It has this shape:

```
Header1,
Data1,
Data4
...

Header2,
Data2,
Data5,
...

Header3
Data3
Data6
...
```

The end goal is to get my delimited data in a common format (CSV or similar), like:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
Data1,Data2,Data3
Data4,Data5,Data6
...
```

The strategy I was thinking of employing was to join 'distant' lines in vscode by alt-clicking distant lines and then using the `Ctrl+Shift+P:Join Lines` palette command, but that didn't seem to work.

I was wondering if anyone here knew how to join 'distant lines' in vscode
(or if not that, provide an alternate strategy).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have any comma's at the end of a line remove it
2. Make sure you have the same number of lines under each header

Now for every block

1. Place the cursor at start of line `Header2`
2. Now with `Ctrl+Alt+DownArrow` add multi Cursors or use `Shift+Alt+MouseClick` at the last line belonging to `Header2`
3. Select the whole line: `Shift+End`
4. Cut the content: `Ctrl+X`
5. With `ArrowUp` move the cursors up so the first cursor is on the line with `Header1`
6. Got to end of line, Add `,` , Paste `Header2` lines: `End` `,` `Ctrl+V`

You can also start with the last block and add it to the previous block, now the cursors can stay on the same line to pick up the content and move it to the end of the previous block.

At the end remove all the empty lines.